# ApplicationDeployment.CheckForUpdateAsync Method handling exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, updates

I seem to be having an odd issue w/ the `ApplicationDeployment.CheckForUpdateAsync` Method.  I have it, currently, on a timer, that checks the server for an update at a predetermined interval.  The reason for this is that we need to ensure everyone is on the latest release, and when a new release is available, to notify everyone that it's available.

However, while it works fine if the server is online, if there is a networking error, or the server goes offline during the check, .NET returns a `Socket` or `WebException` error.

I have tried to catch the errors:

```
        try
        {
            _ad.CheckForUpdateAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

For example, but even if i put `WebException` or any other type of exception in that catch, it doesn't seem to catch it.  I assume that's because the `CheckForUpdateAsync()` takes place on a seperate thread.

Is there any way to reliably catch those errors so i do not have random `.NET errors` popping  up during operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check errors on [ApplicationDeployment.CheckForUpdateAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.checkforupdateasync.aspx) Method by adding `CheckForUpdateCompleted` even as below

```
ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
ad.CheckForUpdateCompleted += new CheckForUpdateCompletedEventHandler(ad_CheckForUpdateCompleted);
```

in the

```
void ad_CheckForUpdateCompleted(object sender, CheckForUpdateCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
       // e.Error details here 
    }
}
```

you can find `InvalidDeploymentException` and `DeploymentDownloadException` details from the Error property of the CheckForUpdateCompleted event.

Comment: I did not expect it to return in that location; given that the check fails, i wouldn't expect the completedevent to fire.  But i'll give it a shot, and lyk if it fails for me :)  Ty!

Comment: since this is async method result need to see on complete event read more on MSDN